# Internet Explorer Profiler

Tags: internet-explorer

Is there any profiler sort of tool which can debug which javascript/object in the DOM is causing the Internet Explorer to hang/crash. The CPU usage is going to more than 60% and I want to know the reason behind it, which script/Flash Object is causing that.

Thanks for the help.

---

I am trying to Profile IE6 as the browser hangs when the page is loaded, the page contains various things like LightBox, Flash Player and lots of JS. Once the page is browsed, the CPU utilisation of the IE process becomes more than 60 % which is not the case with all other pages of my site.

Thus wanted to know which script/DOM element is causing that CPU utilization, I used Debug Diagnostic Tools to check IE6 process memory utilization but it gives me COM component functions which are causing that Memory usage and I am not getting which script on my page is causing that.

I got the result as JScript.dll memory usage, Flash10c.ocx usage etc.

Fiddler is also not the right choice as I dont want to see the time taken to load a particular JS, Image, CSS.

I want something like a Ants Profiler which gives the details of each function being executed on the server side code and their CPU/Memory usage.

This profiler should look out for Client Side code rather than server side code which Ants do.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: There are a couple of options. Check [here](http://www.jarrodgoddard.com/web-development/internet-explorer-7-javascript-debugging)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer 8 has profiling built in under Developer Tools (press F12).
There's a Profiler tab in the blue bar.

Answer (score 0):

I found a useful tool sIEve at [link text](http://dertompson.com/2008/03/10/fixing-memory-leaks-of-internet-explorer-6/)

This tool showed me the possibilities where the memory leak can happen and looking onto them I could trace out the div which was creating error.

Thanks,
Ashish Jain